# Blazor WASM problems with css

Tags: css, blazor, blazor-webassembly

For some reason, my Blazor WASM project won't render a video file properly. The CSS for the video tag does not apply when I run my project.

Here is my video html tag:

```
<header>
   <div class="overlay"></div>

   <video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
      <source src="/videos/background.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
   </video>
</header>
```

CSS styling for the video tag:

```
header {
position: relative;
background-color: black;
height: 75vh;
min-height: 25rem;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
```

}

```
header video {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
z-index: 0;
-ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
```

}

Comment: css is in component.razor.css? or in general css file in wwwroot?

Comment: @fingers10 Yes, css is in component.razor.css file.

Comment: did you add reference to this following stylesheet in `index.html` -  `<link href="YOURPROJECTNAME.styles.css" rel="stylesheet">`?

Comment: Somehow the issue got fixed, I think because of a new VS 2022 update or that I moved the video CSS to a separate .css file. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed. I am not 100 how I did it, but most likely it was because I moved the video CSS code to another file and referenced it in the index.html file. Also, there was a new VS 2022 update, that also might have fixed the problem.